# ffmpeg How to add multiple drawtext to one input video

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to add two texts to a video. First text appears in the bottom right for the first 6 seconds, and the second text at the center of the video for the last 3 seconds.

Below is my code:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf drawtext="text='Stack Overflow': fontcolor=white: borderw=2: fontfile=Arial Black: fontsize=w*0.04: x=(w-text_w)-(w*0.04): y=(h-text_h)-(w*0.04): enable='between(t,0,6)'", -vf drawtext="text='Stack Overflow': fontcolor=white: borderw=2: fontfile=Arial Black: fontsize=w*0.04: x=(w-text_w)/2: y=(h-text_h)/2: enable='between(t,7,10)'" -codec:a copy output2.mp4
```

I don't get any error running the above code but in the output file, only the second drawtext is applied.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The **drawtext** should be put into one `-vf` (using "`[in]`/`[out]`" is optional):

```
ffmpeg -i input.m4 -vf "[in]drawtext=text='Stack Overflow': \
fontcolor=white: borderw=2: fontfile=Arial Black: fontsize=w*0.04: \
x=(w-text_w)-(w*0.04): y=(h-text_h)-(w*0.04): enable='between(t,0,6)', \
drawtext=text='Stack Overflow': fontcolor=white: borderw=2: \
fontfile=Arial Black: fontsize=w*0.04: x=(w-text_w)/2: y=(h-text_h)/2: \
enable='between(t,7,10)'[out]" -codec:a copy output2.mp4
```

↳ [10.47 drawtext : ffmpeg documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-drawtext-1)